# OleDBConnection Error in C#

Tags: c#, oledb

I am using C# to connect to my MS SQL database with OleDBConnection. I can log in successfully by SSMS, but not by OleDBConnection.

I get an exception such as:

> [DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Invalid Instance()).] Invalid connection.

Below is my connection string:

`Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Pemmrsist Security Info=True;Data Source=127.0.0.1;Initial Catalog=Test_DB;User ID=test;Pwd=testdb;Connect Timeout=15`

and I have added the `test` login.

Comment: Code and connection string will be of help here

Comment: Yes, please post the code.

Comment: Hello. You already check your connection string? 
http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Post what you got so far..

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have added my connection string

Comment: Why are you not using `using System.Data.SqlClient;`

Comment: I've solved my problem. I'll post it below as answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've enabled `TCP/IP` and I add `port 1433`, so I modify my connection IP to `127.0.0.1,1433`. Then, it worked.

Comment: @DJKRAZE thanks for your reply. The ip of connection may be dynamically, so I did not add it into .config.